# Error: Multiply defined symbol, how to fix?

Tags: assembly, mips

My code is getting errors when I'm trying to compile it. What is the problem.

Here is the error for my MIPS code. The code segment is below:

/home/fac/wrc/bin/rasm -l prime.asm > prime.lst

89 0048 012A582A
Loop:  slt $t3, $t1, $t2  # if ($t1 < $t2) $t3 = 1
Error: Multiply defined symbol

150 00c4 01AE782A
Loop:  slt $t7, $t5, $t6  # if ($t2 < $t3) $t7 = 1
Error: Multiply defined symbol

There were 2 fatal errors
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'prime.obj' failed
make: *** [prime.obj] Error 2

What should I do to fix this error

Code in MIPS Assembly:

```
find_primes:
        addi    $sp,$sp,-40     # allocate stack frame (on doubleword boundary)
        sw      $ra, 32($sp)    # store the ra & s reg's on the stack
        sw      $s7, 28($sp)
        sw      $s6, 24($sp)
        sw      $s5, 20($sp)
        sw      $s4, 16($sp)
        sw      $s3, 12($sp)
        sw      $s2, 8($sp)
        sw      $s1, 4($sp)
        sw      $s0, 0($sp)

# ######################################
# ##### BEGIN STUDENT CODE BLOCK 1 #####

addi $t1, $zero, MIN # Insert minimum value MIN = 3 in register $t1

addi $t2, $zero, MAX # Insert maximum value MAX = 102 in register $t2

Loop:  slt $t3, $t1, $t2  # if ($t1 < $t2) $t3 = 1
             # else $t3 = 0

beq $t3, $zero, L2 # if ($t3 == $zero) go to L2
jal is_prime

add $t4, $zero, $v0

syscall

bne $t4, $zero, print_number

addi $t1, $t1, 1 # $t1 = $t1 + 1

j Loop # go to the Loop

L2:

# ###### END STUDENT CODE BLOCK 1 ######
# ######################################






is_prime:
        addi    $sp,$sp,-40     # allocate stackframe (doubleword aligned)
        sw      $ra, 32($sp)    # store the ra & s reg's on the stack
        sw      $s7, 28($sp)
        sw      $s6, 24($sp)
        sw      $s5, 20($sp)
        sw      $s4, 16($sp)
        sw      $s3, 12($sp)
        sw      $s2, 8($sp)
        sw      $s1, 4($sp)
        sw      $s0, 0($sp)

# ######################################
# ##### BEGIN STUDENT CODE BLOCK 2 #####

addi $t5, $zero, 2
add $t6, $zero, $a0

Loop:  slt $t7, $t5, $t6  # if ($t2 < $t3) $t7 = 1
                          # else $t7 = 0

beq $t7, $zero, Exit # if ($t7 == $zero) go to Exit

rem $t6, $a0, $t5

beq $t6, $zero, L1 # if ($t7 == $zero) go to L1 


addi $t5, $t5, 1 # $t5 = $t5 + 1

j Loop # go to the Loop

L1:
    addi $v0, $v0, 0  # The value of $v0 is zero

Exit:
    addi $v0, $v0, 1 # The value of $v0 is one

# ###### END STUDENT CODE BLOCK 2 ######
# ######################################
```

Comment: You have multiple labels named `Loop`. Give them unique names.

Comment: There is still a problem with this program. I'm trying to print out all the prime numbers from 3 to 101 inclusive. However this is what is being print out:
11
268435456 (an infinite number of times). How can I fix it.

Comment: That's a separate question.  Normally I'd say ask a new question, but the label question is obvious from the error message and probably not useful to future readers.  So if you want to completely rewrite this question (including the title and all the question body) to be about debugging this program, go ahead.  Be sure to make it a [mcve] including info you find from single-stepping with the debugger.